# Is there any difference in hitting an empty wall vs a full wall with the head, considered the surface is the same? Which one is more painful?

Tags: forces, energy, speed

It sounds to me like empty objects are less painful, but not sure why and what is the physical reason for this. I also tried an experiment where I was throwing eggs against two different walls, but the results are not very clear.

Of course, we are considering the same speed of the objects and the same surface of the walls.

The question is: is there any difference in hitting an empty wall vs a full wall with the head, considered the surface is the same? Which one is more painful?

Comment: I don't understand your question. According to Newton's law, every action has an equal and opposite reaction. So, you'll feel the same amount of pain. But, if the wall is too much empty, you'll find yourself on the other side after the experiment.

Comment: @lee "[...] you'll feel the same amount of pain" is not necessarily true. If you put a pillow between yourself and the wall, Newton's laws still apply, but it will hurt much less.

Comment: @lee    *you'll find yourself on the other side after the experiment.* Isn't necessarily true. lee doesn't understand the question, clearly.

Answer (score 2):

The content of the "wall" doesn't matter as long as that content doesn't change the collision. If both walls cause you to stop in the same amount of time then you have experienced the same force, and hence the same "pain".

If the "full" vs. "emptiness" does influence the collision by causing the stopping times to be different, then the wall that stops you in a longer amount of time will be less painful. This would mostly likely be the case in the "empty" wall scenario if the wall is somewhat less rigid than the "full" wall, but since your question doesn't give any specifics here this would just be speculation.

Answer (score 1):

The amount of damage done is usually a monotonic function of the force applied. That is, the larger the force, the larger the damage. Now, a full wall will commonly be very rigid and not move a lot when you hit it. The object hitting it will have to come to a stop over a short distance, the force will be large.

Empty walls are often less rigid, because they can flex into the empty space. This means a larger distance to decelerate the object hitting it, and a smaller force being applied. If the object is a person, it will feel less pain that way.

Comment: This is sorta true -- but it depends on the compressibility (as well as the deflection depth) of the wall surface.  I'd rather hit a wall of 1-inch foam backed with cinderblocks than hit a wall of  1/8-inch titanium w/ no backing.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft That's why there are a lot of "usually", "commonly", and "often" in there.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft The question states the "surface is the same".